# Powershell move-item is not moving files into subfolders

Tags: powershell

The goal is to move sql log backups from a local server to a share folder with all of the other servers.  The log backup program creates a local folder for each server and AG group it finds so it is possible to have multiple folders on the local server.  The destination share is a combination of all the servers but we are sure no folder names are duplicated.

I cannot use ROBOCOPY because of the folder structure.  I have multiple folders on each server and I don't know what their names will be.

I'm expecting the folder structure to be the same from the source to the target, but the files are all getting dumped in the target and not in subfolders of the target.

Please let me know what I'm missing in my syntax. I'm expecting the identical folder structure on the destination, but the bold part is missing in the destination.

I have some addition code to select the correct folders and loop through each one, but this is the problem statement:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "M:\MSSQL\LOGS\Source-Server" -Recurse  | Copy-Item -destination  "\\sqlbackupslas\sqldatabackup\CTM-Source-Server" -WhatIf
```

results:

```
What- if: Preforming the operation "Move File" on target "Item: M:\MSSQL\LOGS\CTM-DBTOOLS02\log\ctm-db-tools02_202011241200_log.trn Destination: \\sqlbackupslas\sqldatabackup\CTM-DBTOOLS02\ctm-db-tools02_202011241200_log.trn"
```

but I expect it to be placed in a folder
\sqlbackupslas\sqldatabackup\CTM-DBTOOLS02\ **log**

Comment: Why script this vs using the built-in Robocopy.exe and use it's mirroring options? Robocopy is purpose-built for these sorts of use cases and more performant than the PowerShell cmdlets. You can use Robocopy in your scripts.

Comment: I don't think robocopy will work because i want to copy from several servers to a single share and I don't know how many folders I am starting with.  If i do a mirror, it will delete the other folders on the share

Comment: Why not? Just pass in a list of servers and loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I will rewrite it using robocopy /mov.  I don't see a parameter to purge the destination, is that an option with robocopy or do I need to add a del statement in my loop?  I'd like to delete items older than 2 days after I copy.

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy/? --- will list all possibilities.  As shown, there is a purge switch. ***[/PURGE:: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.]***.

Yet even if it did not, if the file/folder names are the same it will overwrite, if not, then sure you can do a delete, but that would mean comparison to be sure before you did. Robocopy has options for mirroring. source and destination. ***[/MIR:: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).]***

```
 robocopy /?

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, 25 November, 2020 12:12:23
              Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

::
:: Copy options :
::
                 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
                 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
             /LEV:n :: only copy the top n LEVels of the source directory tree.

                 /Z :: copy files in restartable mode.
                 /B :: copy files in Backup mode.
                /ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.
                 /J :: copy using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).
            /EFSRAW :: copy all encrypted files in EFS RAW mode.

  /COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                       (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps, X=Skip alt data streams).
                       (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

 
               /SEC :: copy files with SECurity (equivalent to /COPY:DATS).
           /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).
            /NOCOPY :: COPY NO file info (useful with /PURGE).
            /SECFIX :: FIX file SECurity on all files, even skipped files.
            /TIMFIX :: FIX file TIMes on all files, even skipped files.

             /PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
               /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).

               /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
              /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).

     /A+:[RASHCNET] :: add the given Attributes to copied files.
     /A-:[RASHCNET] :: remove the given Attributes from copied files.

            /CREATE :: CREATE directory tree and zero-length files only.
               /FAT :: create destination files using 8.3 FAT file names only.
               /256 :: turn off very long path (> 256 characters) support.

             /MON:n :: MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
             /MOT:m :: MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.

      /RH:hhmm-hhmm :: Run Hours - times when new copies may be started.
                /PF :: check run hours on a Per File (not per pass) basis.

             /IPG:n :: Inter-Packet Gap (ms), to free bandwidth on slow lines.

                /SJ :: copy Junctions as junctions instead of as the junction targets.
                /SL :: copy Symbolic Links as links instead of as the link targets.

            /MT[:n] :: Do multi-threaded copies with n threads (default 8).
                       n must be at least 1 and not greater than 128.
                       This option is incompatible with the /IPG and /EFSRAW options.
                       Redirect output using /LOG option for better performance.

 /DCOPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for directories (default is /DCOPY:DA).
                       (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps, E=EAs, X=Skip alt data streams).

           /NODCOPY :: COPY NO directory info (by default /DCOPY:DA is done).

         /NOOFFLOAD :: copy files without using the Windows Copy Offload mechanism.

          /COMPRESS :: Request network compression during file transfer, if applicable.

::
:: File Selection Options :
::
                 /A :: copy only files with the Archive attribute set.
                 /M :: copy only files with the Archive attribute and reset it.
    /IA:[RASHCNETO] :: Include only files with any of the given Attributes set.
    /XA:[RASHCNETO] :: eXclude files with any of the given Attributes set.

 /XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.
 /XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.

                /XC :: eXclude Changed files.
                /XN :: eXclude Newer files.
                /XO :: eXclude Older files.
                /XX :: eXclude eXtra files and directories.
                /XL :: eXclude Lonely files and directories.
                /IS :: Include Same files.
                /IT :: Include Tweaked files.

             /MAX:n :: MAXimum file size - exclude files bigger than n bytes.
             /MIN:n :: MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes.

          /MAXAGE:n :: MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
          /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
          /MAXLAD:n :: MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n.
          /MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.
                       (If n < 1900 then n = n days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).

               /FFT :: assume FAT File Times (2-second granularity).
               /DST :: compensate for one-hour DST time differences.

                /XJ :: eXclude symbolic links (for both files and directories) and Junction points.
               /XJD :: eXclude symbolic links for Directories and Junction points.
               /XJF :: eXclude symbolic links for Files.

                /IM :: Include Modified files (differing change times).
::
:: Retry Options :
::
               /R:n :: number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million.
               /W:n :: Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds.

               /REG :: Save /R:n and /W:n in the Registry as default settings.

               /TBD :: Wait for sharenames To Be Defined (retry error 67).

               /LFSM :: Operate in low free space mode, enabling copy pause and resume (see Remarks).

               /LFSM:n[KMG] :: /LFSM, specifying the floor size in n [K:kilo,M:mega,G:giga] bytes.

::
:: Logging Options :
::
                 /L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.
                 /X :: report all eXtra files, not just those selected.
                 /V :: produce Verbose output, showing skipped files.
                /TS :: include source file Time Stamps in the output.
                /FP :: include Full Pathname of files in the output.
             /BYTES :: Print sizes as bytes.

                /NS :: No Size - don't log file sizes.
                /NC :: No Class - don't log file classes.
               /NFL :: No File List - don't log file names.
               /NDL :: No Directory List - don't log directory names.

                /NP :: No Progress - don't display percentage copied.
               /ETA :: show Estimated Time of Arrival of copied files.

          /LOG:file :: output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log).
         /LOG+:file :: output status to LOG file (append to existing log).

       /UNILOG:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (overwrite existing log).
      /UNILOG+:file :: output status to LOG file as UNICODE (append to existing log).

               /TEE :: output to console window, as well as the log file.

               /NJH :: No Job Header.
               /NJS :: No Job Summary.

           /UNICODE :: output status as UNICODE.

::
:: Job Options :
::
       /JOB:jobname :: take parameters from the named JOB file.
      /SAVE:jobname :: SAVE parameters to the named job file
              /QUIT :: QUIT after processing command line (to view parameters). 
              /NOSD :: NO Source Directory is specified.
              /NODD :: NO Destination Directory is specified.
                /IF :: Include the following Files.

::
:: Remarks :
::
       Using /PURGE or /MIR on the root directory of the volume formerly caused 
       robocopy to apply the requested operation on files inside the System 
       Volume Information directory as well. This is no longer the case; if 
       either is specified, robocopy will skip any files or directories with that 
       name in the top-level source and destination directories of the copy session.

       The modified files classification applies only when both source 
       and destination filesystems support change timestamps (e.g., NTFS) 
       and the source and destination files have different change times but are 
       otherwise the same. These files are not copied by default; specify /IM 
       to include them.

       The /DCOPY:E flag requests that extended attribute copying should be 
       attempted for directories. Note that currently robocopy will continue 
       if a directory's EAs could not be copied. This flag is also not included 
       in /COPYALL.

       Using /LFSM requests robocopy to operate in 'low free space mode'. 
       In that mode, robocopy will pause whenever a file copy would cause the 
       destination volume's free space to go below a 'floor' value, which 
       can be explicitly specified by the LFSM:n[KMG] form of the flag. 
       If /LFSM is specified with no explicit floor value, the floor is set to 
       ten percent of the destination volume's size. 
       Low free space mode is incompatible with /MT, /EFSRAW, /B, and /ZB.
```

See also the examples here:

> https://techdiip.com/robocopy-command-explained
>
> https://www.webservertalk.com/robocopy-script-to-copy-files-from-one-server-to-another